# Saving image: A generic error occurred in GDI+. (vb.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, gdi+

I need to save an image after opening it in from an OFD.
This is my code atm:

```
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
ofd.Multiselect = True
ofd.ShowDialog()


For Each File In ofd.FileNames
   Image.FromFile(File).Save("C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\e\tmp.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.png)
Next
```

And on the line `Image.FromFile(File).Save("C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\e\tmp.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.png)` it comes up with the error.

(note: the application will be built on so that's just my first code and it will need to be saved not copied)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd check two things:

1. That the directory you're saving to
   exists
2. That you have write permissions to
   this directory

Comment: Well I thought I had checked the directory existed but it didn't Thanks so much, I really hate it though when I spend ages trying to find why it's not working and then knowing it as something ridiculously simple :)

Comment: I'm glad you're the only person on the planet that that happens to! :)

Answer (score 5):

Opening or saving an Image puts a lock on the file.  Overwriting this file requires you to first call Dispose() on the Image object that holds the lock.

I don't really understand your code but you'd have to do it this way:

```
    For Each File In ofd.FileNames
        Using img As Image = Image.FromFile(File)
            img.Save("C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\e\tmp.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        End Using
    Next
```

The Using statement ensures that the img object is disposed and the file lock is released.

Answer (score 1):

The Image puts a lock.

For example, i used this buffer images to save in to a memorystream.

```
byte[] ImageData = new Byte[0];
if (BackGroundImage != null)
    {
        Bitmap BufferImage = new Bitmap(BackGroundImage);
        MemoryStream ImageStream = new MemoryStream();
        BufferImage.Save(ImageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        BufferImage.Dispose();
        ImageData = ImageStream.ToArray();
        ImageStream.Dispose();


        //write the length of the image data...if zero, the deserialier won't load any image
        DataStream.Write(ImageData.Length);
        DataStream.Write(ImageData, 0, ImageData.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        DataStream.Write(ImageData.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason of this is that the stream (MemoryStream or any other stream) that you have loaded the main image from has been disposed!

Such this case:

This is an extension method that converts a byte array to a bitmap, but using statement will dispose the memory stream, this will cause this error always:

```
    public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                return new Bitmap(ms);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems occuring because `Image.Drawing.FromFile()` method lock opened file !

I have encountered same problem and I have resolved this issue using following workaround.

```
Public sFileName as string
Public img as Drawing.Image

Public Sub OpenFile(ByVal sFile As String)
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(sFile)
    sFileName = sFile
End Sub

Public Sub Update()
    Try
        img.Save("NEW.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        img.Dispose
        System.IO.File.Delete(sFileName)
        System.IO.File.Move("NEW.jpeg", sFileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
    EndTry
End Sub
```

The workaround consist to

1. save modified image in another file named here `NEW.jpeg`
2. dispose `img` object to release it
3. rename created file to original filename

Between `OpenFile()` and `Update()` methods, I call a specific method to change capture's date of a photo.

```
Public Sub SetDateTime(ByVal sDate As String)

    Dim ascii As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    Dim propItem As System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem

    propItem = img.GetPropertyItem(&H132) 'PropertyTagDateTime

    propItem.Value = ascii.GetBytes(sDate)
    propItem.Value(19) = 0

    img.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
    propItem.Id = &H9003
    img.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
    propItem.Id = &H9004
    img.SetPropertyItem(propItem)
    propItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is part of a program that rename capture's date of photos when camera's date has not been initalized correctly.