# How To Clear A Picture Box Image?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm creating a key logger in vb 2008 for my home computer that can send keys

records & screen shoots at my E-mail. It has a textbox, 3 buttons, a picturebox and some

timers,

actually the process is that in every 3 minutes button1 take a screen shoot  (at 2.90 minutes)

OK, then button2 save it in "C:/mydir/hidden folder/" (at 2.95 minutes) then button3 send it

via Email as a attachment (at 3.00 minutes), its work fine in first round or first 3 minutes.

but in Repeating Process or in 2nd round or after 3 minutes it give error that means image is

in use, I want to break the link between image and my program (key logger) there for my

keylogger can delete or REPLACE old Screen Shoot With New One.

and the process repeat again & again, and send Screen Shoots With NO error.

My English is not so good. Sorry for Spell and grammatical Mistakes.

Comment: You are forgetting to call the image object's Dispose() method after saving it.  That leaves a lock on the file, preventing you from overwriting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving image: A generic error occurred in GDI+. (vb.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050996/saving-image-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-vb-net)

Comment: sorry, but i don't know any thing about dispose() can you answer the solution codes? how to use dispose method? post your answer with detail. thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us image saving code so we can help you

Comment: Image Saving Button Code.

CODE:

Private Sub btn_SaveAs_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_SaveAs.Click

        PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\WINDOWS\folder\file1.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub

Comment: Don't post the code in a comment.  Edit your question and add the requested code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will dispose the image after saving it

```
Using b As New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
    'Do some code to fill the image
    b.Save("C:\Somewhere\image.jpg")
End Using
```

Comment: You are Right, when i use Dispose() in attachment it solved!! Well Thanks.