# save image from picturebox in stream format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

i wanna save a picture that loaded in a picturebox to stream .when i save in png format it work properly but when i want save it in other formats i get

> A Generic error occured in GDI + exception

its my code:

```
Image Img = pictureBox1.Image;
byte[] inputImage = new byte[Img.Width * Img.Height];
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
ms.Read(inputImage, 0, Img.Width * Img.Height);

if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(Img.RawFormat))
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(Img.RawFormat))
{
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
}
else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png.Equals(Img.RawFormat))
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
else if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp.Equals(Img.RawFormat))
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

Comment: I just copied the whole your code in a C# program (.Net3.5) and it ran with no error! I could save with different formats!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving image: A generic error occurred in GDI+. (vb.net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050996/saving-image-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-vb-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public Stream ImageToStream(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms, format);
    return  ms;
}
```

and use it:

```
using(Stream stream = ImageToStream(pictureBox1.Image, 
                           System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif))
{
    ...
}
```