# I try to save a photo every 30 secs to temporary dir with a different name each,but it only save once

Tags: vb.net

I try to save a photo every 30 secs to temporary dir with a different name each,but it only save once and give me an error 
this is my error

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

stacktrace

```
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
```

at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at WindowsApplication1.Form1.savetempfoto() in Form1.vb:line 372

and the line error is

```
PB1.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

this is my code

```
Public Function temdirx()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(tempdir)
End Function


Public Function timesavetemp()
    Timer2.Start()

End Function

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    timetosavetemp = timetosavetemp + 1

    If timetosavetemp >= 30 Then
        savetempfoto()
        timetosavetemp = 0

    End If
End Sub
Public Function savetempfoto()
    Dim PB1 As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
    'Dim frame As Long 'individual frames
    'Dim strings As String

    'strings = frame
    'Dim path As String = String.Format("C:\Mediamemebuilderpro\MDAL1Image{0}.jpg", nametosave)
    'PB1.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    'PB1.Save("C:\Mediamemebuilderpro\MDAL1Image" & strings & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    'frame += 1
    Dim filename As String = "MDAL1Image" 'Change as needed
    Dim path As String = String.Format("C:\Mediamemebuilderpro\{0}{1}.jpg", filename, nametosave)
    PB1.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    timetosavetemp = 0
End Function
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Mediamemebuilderpro", "*.*")

        ListBox1.Items.Add(file)

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button20_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button20.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

End Sub
```

Comment: Show how you create the timer. Set its time to 30 minutes. As for the error. check to make sure that the save location exists and that you have permission to modify it. You also have 30 sec in the title but 30 min in the body of the question. you need to clarify that

Comment: The Save() method puts a lock on the file.  So it will fail the second time, you can't overwrite a locked file.  Pretty basic bug, you forgot to dispose the bitmap.  Use the `Using` statement.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi tanks for the replay can you please give me an example how to do?

Comment: @ines wrap the image in a `Using` statement so that it is disposed automatically once it goes out of scope. There are many answers on this site that show you how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of reasons why you would get that error.  Start here:

[Saving image: A generic error occurred in GDI+. (vb.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050996/saving-image-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-vb-net)

Often times it's something simple.

Comment: well i have just solved the error but i am not able to automatic save the photo every 30 minutes on a tempdir with a different name each time so i like to build a sort of undo changes so its because i need to save the same photo every 30 minutes with a different name each time.

Comment: Just use the timer control, set it to activate every thirty minutes, save the photo.  You can reset to clock when the user execute the save function.

Comment: Tanks for the replay i have all ready try this but its only save once and wen it try to save the second its give me gdi error

Comment: Probably because the file already exists and you need to set the save function to overwrite an existing file.

Comment: well this is true but what i mean is about is: i need to make a backup from the photo and keep it on the backup folder and wen its do the save again make a new photo with a different name like "MDLABS_1" , 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: well this is true but what i mean is about is: i need to make a backup from the photo and keep it on the backup folder and wen its do the save again make a new photo with a different name like "MDLABS_1" , 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: In that case you will need to track the filename, I would use a static counter and a static string variable to track the original filename.  When the save occurs, check the filename passed in the parameter with the static variable, if the same concatenate the counter and increment or increment the counter and then concatenate, which ever works for you.  If the filename is different, reset the counter and save the new filename in the static variable and save the file.